# Compilation error ambiguous reference to method when using typed collection

Tags: java

In the same class i have two overloading methods:

```
public static <T> void foo(Collection<T> collection, T valueToAppend);
public static <T> void foo(Collection<T> collection, Collection<T> valueToAppend);
```

The following test should call The second method:

```
 @Test 
   public void testFoo() {
   ArrayList ftList = Lists.newArrayList();
   List<Double> doubleList = Lists.newArrayList(1.0, 2.0);
   foo(ftList, doubleList);
}
```

When i run the test i get the following compilation error:

> reference to foo is ambiguous, both method foo(java.util.Collection,T) in path.to.class and method foo(java.util.Collection,java.util.Collection) in path.to.class match.

I'm passing a collection in the second argument so why doesn't the compiler know to 
go to the second method?

 If i change the methods signature and remove the generics from the first parameter i will 
not get compilation error, why is that?

Comment: Because `<T>` can also be `Collection`.. It's a type like any other.

Comment: Arraylist isn't a `Collection<T>`

Comment: Unrelated but shouldn't it be `T valueToAppend`?

Comment: You have used the raw type `ArrayList`. I think that may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my explanation. When the compiler has to choose between overloadings, it always chooses the most specific overloading. When you strip the type information from the first parameter, the signatures become

```
public static <T> void foo(Collection collection, T valueToAppend)
public static <T> void foo(Collection collection, Collection<T> valueToAppend)
```

The second of these is more specific. Any pair of parameters that can be accepted by the second method can also be accepted by the first, because any `Collection` is an `Object`. Therefore when you strip the type parameter away, there is no ambiguity - the second method is chosen if you pass two `Collection`s.

However with the type information, the signatures look like this:

```
public static <T> void foo(Collection<T> collection, T valueToAppend)
public static <T> void foo(Collection<T> collection, Collection<T> valueToAppend)
```

Neither of these signatures is more specific than the other. The parameters `new ArrayList<String>()` and `"Foo"` will be accepted by the first signature but not the second. The parameters `new ArrayList<String>()` and `new ArrayList<String>()` will be accepted by the second signature but not the first.

So if both signatures apply, there is a problem.

You are trying to pass a raw `ArrayList` and a `List<Double>`. Because you are using a raw type `ArrayList` (which you should never do), `ftList` can pass as a `Collection<T>` for *any* `T` (Try it. Try passing a raw `List` to a method with parameter of type `List<String>`. It works). Therefore you only need to see that `doubleList` matches the second parameter for *both* overloadings. It matches the first signature if `T` is `List<Double>` and matches the second signature if `T` is `Double`.

Comment: Thank you For the detailed answer. Could you please explain why passing a raw type ArrayList as the 1st parameter wouldn't automatically define <T> as Object?

Comment: @D.C It defines `<T>` as Object. And this is your problem.

Comment: @Tom but if <T> is Object then i expect the signatures will look like that: `public static void foo(Collection<Object> collection, Object valueToAppend)
public static void boo(Collection<Object> collection, Collection<Object> valueToAppend)`. But these signatures does not causing compilation error.

Comment: @D.C I guess the reason is as follows. Generics did not exist until java 1.5 so before that you had to write `List`. However even then most `List`s were `List`s of objects of the same type e.g. `["foo", "bar"]` or `[1, 2, 3]`. When they introduced generics they wanted new code to work with old. They wanted the first `List` to be accepted by a method requiring a `List<String>` and the second to be accepted by a method requiring a `List<Integer>`. The only way to make it work is to say that a `List` can pass as a `List<T>` for any `T`. It wouldn't work if it had to be a `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because The 2nd Parameter `<T>` could be an `Collection` also , the interpreter is confused whether it is a `Collection<T>` or `<T>`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can not identify between `<T>` and `Collection<T>`